# Log in SQL Server Express for audit

Tags: sql-server-express

It is possible in SQL Server Express have a log of all operations "SELECT / UPDATE / INSERT / DELETE" being made.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx), though. Freeware alternative [is here](http://code.google.com/p/sqlexpressprofiler/downloads/list)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the express edition you do not have "SQL Server Profiler". But here is a free open source alternative:

http://code.google.com/p/sqlexpressprofiler/

Answer (score 0):

We use [something similar to this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/pop-rivetts-sql-server-faq-no.5-pop-on-the-audit-trail/) with SQL Server 2005.  It should work in the express edition.